# Removing Logic out of the view in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Whilst prototyping something I quickly used some logic in my view to get it working (I've always thought this was a bad idea and it should not be done?). When I previously worked on Rails projects we could make use of view helpers, but working on a NodeJS/Express app I am unsure how to approach this.

I have this in my view for example

```
<% if (fixture.team_name == "Team 1" && fixture.team_stadium == "Stadium 1") { %>
  <span class="label label-success">Team 1</span>
<% } %>
```

There will be a time when I would want a case statement to decide on what html to deliver but I won't want to put that in the view of course, just call a helper function maybe.

How is this done with Node/Express?

Comment: when you say what `HTML` to deliver, you mean you have multiple EJS templates for a specific route and you want to use a case statement to render a different one?

Comment: No it's one template but i wanted to avoid logic in the view and just call a function instead, which would just keep the logic separate and away from the view